# Handling eager loading and unsaved associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, eager-loading

How can I handle a scenario where associated records may not be saved to the database?

If I have

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

then adding an `includes` statement for eager loading throws away unsaved records:

```
blog = Blog.new
blog.posts << Post.new
blog.posts # => Return value contains one post
blog.posts.includes(:comments) # => Empty result
```

I could leave out the `includes` statement, but that'd mean slower code if my code interacted with comments and the blog and posts were saved.

I'm using Rails 4.1.